# Cannot find imports after IntelliJ suggested Maven reload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I was just creating a new project and doing creating some JWT Authentication.
I was writing my code and it worked as intended. Suddenly after having created a bunch of code, IntelliJ suggested I would do a Maven reload. I don't per se know why, but I did it as I thought there would be a handy change instead of what happened now.

Now all my imports are invalid, not recognized whilst (I **think**) nothing else changed.

I cannot help but think there is a simple fix for this problem, but I cannot find it anywhere.

I'll include two screenshots of my situation in an imgur link, a before and an after.

[Imgur Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuMYn.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried invalidating cache and restarting IntelliJ?

Comment: I have not, but I did manage to find what the problem was. It works as should now.

The problem was that I encapsulated the dependencies in a dependency manager as a tip from another StackOverflow page. It handled correctly at first but then it completely crashed on me. I took it out and let the dependencies just be without encapsulating it in a dependency manager and it functions as should now.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just delete the question instead of prefixng it with solved or answer your own question.